# mv групповое переименование/перемещение

Tags: linux, bash, перемещение

Почему когда я выполняю команду вида `mv *.k {i..j}.k`, где i, j это некоторые числа, а k - некоторое расширение, mv выводит ошибку:

> указанная цель 'j.k' не является каталогом

при том, что перемещение происходит в этом же каталоге, а i и j подобраны под количество файлов на переименование.

Используемый дистрибутив: Ubuntu 18.04
Bash версии 4.4.20

Answer (score 6, accepted):

программа *mv* делает одно из двух:

1. переименовывает (с перемещением или без) **один** файл:

   ```
   $ mv исходный.файл конечный.файл
   ```
2. перемещает один или более файлов в указанный каталог. традиционный порядок аргументов:

   ```
   $ mv файл ... каталог
   ```

   альтернативный порядок аргументов — сначала каталог назначения, затем файлы:

   ```
   $ mv -t каталог файл ...
   ```

переименовать же несколько файлов **за один вызов** эта программа не умеет.

---

чтобы не писать кучу отдельных команд переименования/перемещения, можно воспользоваться языком программирования, встроенным в программу-оболочку. вот такой, например, микро-программой (подходит для любой posix-совместимой оболочки):

```
$ n=1; for f in *.k; do mv "$f" "$n.zzz"; n=$((n+1)); done
```

я намеренно использовал в качестве новых имена, заканчивающиеся другим суффиксом, не как у исходных файлов — `.k` — а `.zzz` (это просто для примера). иначе можно потерять информацию: например, если есть два файла `0.k` и `1.k`, то первое же переименование — `0.k` в `1.k` — удалит существующий файл `1.k`.

---

альтернативный [вариант](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/497960/110559) — воспользоваться perl-овой реализацией программы *rename* (при [нескольких установленных реализациях](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/110559) непосредственно к этой реализации можно обратиться по её «родному» имени — `prename`).

например:

```
$ prename 's/.*\.k$/sprintf "%03d.zzz", ++$a/e' *.k -n
rename(0.k, 001.zzz)
rename(1.k, 002.zzz)
$ prename 's/.*\.k$/sprintf "%03d.zzz", ++$a + 20/e' *.k -n
rename(0.k, 021.zzz)
rename(1.k, 022.zzz)
$ prename 's/.*\.k$/sprintf "%03d.zzz", $a++ + 30/e' *.k -n
rename(0.k, 030.zzz)
rename(1.k, 031.zzz)
```

и т.д. и т.п.

дополнительная информация: `$ man prename`

Comment: @user7860670 ваша правка искажает ответ (не будет работать в posix-совместимых оболочках). откатываю.

Answer (score 2):

Есть в большинстве дистрибутивов пакет/скрипт `rename`, немного практичнее голого `mv`.

```
~$ ls ./
one.bak
two.bak
three.bak

~$ rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak

~$ ls ./
one
two
three
```

https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/File-Rename/rename.PL

Answer (score 0):

Можно так все файлы `*.jpg` -> `*.jpeg`:

```
for i in *.jpg ; do mv -v $i `echo $i | awk -F. '{print $1".jpeg"}'`;done
```

но если будут в имени файла точки, то не сработает!

Comment: очевидно же, что точки в именах файлов **уже** присутствуют (пример: `blabla.jpg` - как минимум **одна** точка в имени файла - **есть**), поэтому непонятно ваше последнее замечание.